# Copy member value on stack or access it with pointer?

Tags: c++, c, performance, memory

So I got a structure, that holds an integer. I usually create that structure on the heap. If I now pass a pointer to such a structure into a function and use the integer member, would it be faster if I at first copied the members value on the stack and use that local variable in the function, or should I access the member through the pointer? What is potentially faster? Obviously I dont want to modify the member value. Code example:

Sample structure:

```
struct sample_s
{
  int sample_member;
}
```

Way 1:

```
void sample_func(struct sample_s *sample_instance)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", sample_instance->sample_member);
  }
}
```

Way 2:

```
void sample_func_two(struct sample_s *sample_instance)
{
  int a = sample_instance->sample_member;
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", a);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need a const&, since you are not going to change the values.( case of C++)

Comment: seems very much like premature optimization. Actually I would be surprised if a compiler would generate different output for the two snippets

Comment: Build both variants (with optimization enabled) and compare the generated machine code using a disassembler. I doubt there will be any difference.

Comment: @JeJo It's tagged both C++ and C, so no const&

Comment: just in case you dont know it, this is an awsome tool to investigate such cases: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: There probably will be no or very little difference. You should avoid this kind of optimization because it doesn't really improve your code and can only confuse the readers.

Comment: @ad3angel1s: How about `const struct sample_s *const` instead? That will almost mimic the const reference in C++.

Comment: @Moritz - These are not even micro optimizations, but nano optimizations. A PC running at 4 GHz can perhaps do 10 machine instructions in a nanosecond. If you can remove one of those, will anyone notice? And how do we know that the compiler doesn't do that for you already?

Comment: @BoPersson Well, I do not know. So I asked...

Comment: first approach will dereference pointer and load integer, second - just load integer.
generally speaking, it's highly depends on compiler, but fast inspection using [compiler explorer](https://cppx.godbolt.org/) shows no difference (asm commands just mixed in different order)

Comment: The comment by @Someprogrammerdude offers probably the most practical advice.  There are _[many choices out there for the tools](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/is-there-any-disassembler-to-rival-ida-pro?newreg=9f644a84dcca4bf5a0aedec64015a616)_ needed to follow it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there is a difference even if the parameter is const and restrict : godbolt.org/g/6Gk6j5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific case, `sample_func_two` is *potentially* faster. This is because you're calling an external function, `printf`:

```
printf("%d", sample_instance->sample_member);
```

The compiler probably doesn't know that this call won't modify `*sample_instance`<sup>1</sup>, so it will reload `sample_member` from memory each time through the loop.

Now as for whether that makes an actual difference in the running time of your program, you'll have to benchmark it yourself.

---

<sup>1</sup> The compiler doesn't know because it can't see the code of `printf` (it's in a library somewhere) and `printf` is not declared pure. In fact, `printf` can't be declared pure because depending on the format string it may write through its arguments (with `%n`).

Comment: Does `printf` take a reference as a parameter in C++? If not, how would printf's body get access to those memory addresses?

Comment: Also, if `printf` were declared pure here, the compiler could (and GCC will) optimize the whole function to a single `return;` statement.

Comment: @AlexReinking `sample_instance` could point to a global variable, and unknown functions can access globals directly.